# Filtering WFS exposed data in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, getfeature

I want to create web map of the recycling facilities that will display the nearest facilities with the information on what can be recycle as well as enable the user to search for facilities that recycle specific material(s).

I have a shapefile with point data of recycling facilities and materials are represented in table Materials and are comma separated.

I've uploaded the shapefile and configured it on GeoServer and now I want to create the web map. I'm wondering what is there any way that I can filter data according to one field:

For example (this is a link created by GeoServer):

`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Recycling/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Recycling:RecycleSites_latlong&maxFeatures=1&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&`

And I wonder if I can get something like this (filter and get only Materials field)

`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Recycling/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&`**SomeField=SomeValue&**`typeName=Recycling:RecycleSites_latlong&maxFeatures=1&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&`

I'm a new GeoServer user and do not have links to where I could read more about it.

Comment: Search information by keywords GeoServer and CQL_FILTER and WFS and PROPERTYNAME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user30184 is correct, you should be using CQL_FILTER, some examples here: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html